# get custom field value using Grocery CRUD CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

How can I get the value of a field from another table on my method? And of course, I have the primary key of its table.

I want to do something in add/edit action like this:

```
if (is_empty(value_field_from_another_table)) {
    $crud->edit_fields('first','second');
    $crud->add_fields('first','second');
} else {
    $crud->edit_fields('first');
    $crud->add_fields('first');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);

or

$query = $this->db->get('mytable');


foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
}
```

Comment: your code actually right if we just use CI, but in this case i use GroceryCrud.

Comment: @Mayfield-Four grocery crud is using Codeigniter -_-